# GCP BigQuery doesn’t show preview features in Chinese

Tags: google-bigquery

### Description

After I switched BigQuery UI to preview features by `show preview features` button, the UI cannot be shown completely in Chinese.

I found this issue at 2021/03/05, and my team members were also occurred this.

Screenshot：https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImUDT.png

### What I Try

I tried some solutions as below, but they didn't work for me.

1. Clean cache and cookie
2. Change browser from Chrome to Safari
3. Reboot my mac
4. Re-login

Besides the above solutions, I didn't see other people discussing the issue at internet, like Stack Overflow, Google Groups, and Google Cloud Blog.

How can I change BigQuery UI to hide preview features?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

Just change the language to English.

1. Click `Preferences`.
2. Click `Language & region` and change language to English, then save it.
3. Back to BigQuery.

If you want to keep it be shown and hide preview features in Chinese, just switch to general version by hide preview features button and change language to your language.

That's it.